# java lang runtime exception :unable start activity component info

Tags: java, android

```
hi sir I got this error when my app was launched. When I run my project unfortunately project was stop. This error is coming my log cat. When click on app unfortunately app was stop msg came.
```

I put one text view on activity_xml. When click on navigate to another page but here do not display my first page. There is problem to on mainactivity.java and activity main.xml
error is java.lang.runtime Exception: Unable to start activity component Info{com.example.b/com.example.b.MainActivity}: java. Lang.NullPointerException

```
**mainactivity.java**
andheri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Andheri1);
        andheri.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Context context = null;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,andheri.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });
**activity_xml**
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/untitled1"
    >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Andher1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFE4B5"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Andheri"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#0000CD"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

**mainifest file.**
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.b.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.b.andheri"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: i believe your context is Null as well

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
andheri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Andheri1);
```

to

```
andheri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Andher1);
```

Your TextView id is `id/Andher1` and you're trying to find it as `@+id/Andheri1`. So you got `NPE`.

Answer (score 0):

In the intent you send from main activity, you should set the context to this, not null

and change the id of textview , you missed an 'i'